# Input range to regulate blur value

Tags: javascript, range

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<style>
.imgBlur{
    width:800px;
    float:left;
    height: 450px;
    background: url(img.jpg) no-repeat left center;
    -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
    -moz-filter: blur(20px);
    -o-filter: blur(20px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(20px);
    z-index: 1000;
}
</style>
<body class="body">
                        <input type="range" id="blurValue" class="blurValue" min="0" max="100" step="1"></input>

            <div class="imgBlur" id="imgBlur"></div>


        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hello everyone. My javascript is very poor and i am having trouble finding a solution online for my pickle here. I am trying to make this input range to adjust the value of the blurred div. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Here is your required solution using **`onChange event`**

I have taken a function when range is changed,

```
 <input type="range" id="blurValue" class="blurValue" min="0" max="100" step="1" onChange="changed()"></input>

  function changed()
    {
      var obj = document.getElementById('imgBlur');
      obj.style["-webkit-filter"] = "blur("+document.getElementById("blurValue").value+"px)";
    }
```

This catches the `range change` event and changes the `css` using `javascript`

**`obj.style["-webkit-filter"] = "blur("+document.getElementById("blurValue").value+"px)";`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<style>
.imgBlur{
    width:800px;
    float:left;
    height: 450px;
    background: url("https://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/1458289957powerful-images3.jpg");
    -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
    -moz-filter: blur(20px);
    -o-filter: blur(20px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(20px);
    z-index: 1000;
}
</style>
<body class="body">
                        <input type="range" id="blurValue" class="blurValue" min="0" max="100" step="1" onChange="changed()"></input>

            <div class="imgBlur" id="imgBlur"></div>

<script>
  function changed()
  {
  
  var obj = document.getElementById('imgBlur');
obj.style["-webkit-filter"] = "blur("+document.getElementById("blurValue").value+"px)";
obj.style["-moz-filter"] = "blur("+document.getElementById("blurValue").value+"px)";
obj.style["-o-filter"] = "blur("+document.getElementById("blurValue").value+"px)";
obj.style["-ms-filter"] = "blur("+document.getElementById("blurValue").value+"px)";
obj.style["filter"] = "blur("+document.getElementById("blurValue").value+"px)";

  }
  
 
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above snippet**

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/iZzxfe1Q7xsmGtbWoZLR?p=preview)